# Loop prints last line multiple time - What am I doing wrong? - Using BufferedReader

Tags: java, arrays, loops

This is an assignement for school.
One part of my assignment is to read from a file with 15 elements, store each object in an array and printing the corrected objects in a new file.

Each object has 6 elements in them, separated with a space. So I use a switch case to determine what element is recorded when:

example: space 0 is a Long, space 1 is a String, space 2 is an int, etc.

Here are the elements in the .txt file

```
900876512 Core_Java 2007 Mike_Simon 129.99 568
765867999 Java_Applications_for_Programmers 2010     
David_Wilson_and_Jack_Westman 173.25 672
465979798 From_Java_to_C++ 2008 Linda_Jackson 118.73 439
760098908 Microsoft_VC++ 2006 Garry_Wesley 165.20 416
529086890 Software_Engineering 2005 Alain_Macmillan 219.99 651
765867999 Visual_Basic  2004 Mary_Rosen 108.33 388
529086890 Database_Systems 2007 Peter_Jones_and_Jack_Lewis 157.87 862
800003243 VLSI 2008 Martha_Niclson 117.29 360
200900210 C_# 2007 D._Smith 109.99 387
200900210 Cellular_Communications 2010 Jones_Tomson 127.87 162
542087665 Pattern_Recognition 1998 Sam_Davis 212.59 328
900876512 Programming_Methodologies 2009 Steve_A._Richmond 182.95 590
900876512 OO_Programming 2008 Frank_Raymond 182.25 439
900876512 Design_Pattern 2002 Jay_Franklin 122.15 217
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
```

The problem is that, the loop prints all the object fine if I am inside the J loop. But once outside, if I print the array it will print the last line multiple times like this:

```
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
900876512 Networking_and_Data_Communications 2010 Pete_Jonson 229.25 724
```

I tried to put 
`PublicationArray[i] = obj_publication;` in different places, but nothing works.

For what I saw, each line is read and stored in the array, but then it is override by the next iteration of the loop.

Instead of doing
    i[0]j[0]
    i[0]j[1]
    i[0]j[2]
etc.
it is doing something like this:
    i[0]j[0]
    i[1]j[0]
    i[2]j[0]
etc.

I understand loops but I have no idea what's wrong in this code.

This is an assignment for school, so I have specific things I can and can't do. For example, I can't use Arraylist. Only an array.

This is only a small part of my code, if something isn't clear please tell me so I can fix it. I've been staring at it for so long I know it by heart so I have difficulties seeing from a fresh point of view.

I have created BufferReader and PrintWriter in a try catch around this code. The BufferReader and PrintWriter are closed outside the loop.

EDIT: So I tried to print index of i and j like @Jernej K said but everything seems fine there.

EDIT 2: I thought the problem was my Output method but I realized it was in the loop the problem. When I use `System.out.println(PublicationArray[i].toString);` inside the `j` loop I have a different result than if I am using `System.out.println(PublicationArray[i].toString);` inside the `i` loop.

```
//******************************readline() in files*********************
//holding array...
//this works, prints everything ok.
String[] myHolder = new String[iNumberOfItems];
for(int i=0; i < iNumberOfItems; i++){
    myHolder[i] = myReader.readLine();
    System.out.println("holder "+myHolder[i].toString());
}
//this is the problem...
for(int i=0; i < iNumberOfItems; i++){
    sContainer = myHolder[i];
    sContainer = sContainer.replace('\t', ' ');//replace all tabs with spaces
    if(sContainer == null){
        return;//exit the loop if this read, shouldn't do it but just in case!
    }
    else{//if there is a line
        iCountSpace = 0;//reset space count for each line

      //******************read each char in the line*********************
      for(int j=0; j < sContainer.length(); j++){
      cTemp = sContainer.charAt(j); //read one character at a time

      //***********switch case-->what publication type needs to be recorded? 
      //iCountSpace check at which space the read() is -> if space new space, iCountSpace++ 
        switch(iCountSpace){
        case 0:// case 0 space is Long publication_code
          sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation 
          //if the char is a space
          if(cTemp == cSpace){
            sTemp.deleteCharAt(sTemp.length()-1);//remove the space
            sSwitchTypeContainer = sTemp.toString(); //1-->StringBuffer converting to String
            code = Long.valueOf(sSwitchTypeContainer);//2-->Value of the String converted into a Long
            obj_publication.setCode(code);//3-->value of long placed in code
            iCountSpace ++;//4-->increase value of the space number
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());//4--empty the StringBuffer for next element
           }
        break;
        case 1://case 1 space is String publication_names
            sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation-->casting because we are recording a String
         if(cSpace == cTemp){//if the char is a space, remove it 
            sTemp.deleteCharAt(sTemp.length()-1);//remove the space
            obj_publication.setName(sTemp.toString());//transform the StringBuffer to String
            iCountSpace ++;//increase value of the space number
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());//reset sTemp
         }
         break;
        case 2://case 2 space is int publication_year
         sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation
         if(cSpace == cTemp){//if iTemp is a space...remove it
            sTemp.deleteCharAt(sTemp.length()-1);//remove the space
            sSwitchTypeContainer = sTemp.toString();//1-->converting StringBuffer to String
            iPublication = Integer.valueOf(sSwitchTypeContainer);//2-->converting String to int
            obj_publication.setYear(iPublication);//3-->set year
            iCountSpace++;//4-->increase space number
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());//5-->clear the buffer String
          }
        break;
        case 3://case 3 space is String publication_authorname
         sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation-->string
         if(cSpace == cTemp){//if cTemp is a space...
            sTemp.deleteCharAt(sTemp.length()-1);//remove the space
            obj_publication.setAuthorName(sTemp.toString());//-->set the string in the object
            iCountSpace++;//-->increase space
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());//clear buffer String
         }
         break;
         case 4://case 4 space is double publication_cost 
          sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation
          if(cSpace == cTemp){//if iTemp is a space
            sTemp.deleteCharAt(sTemp.length()-1);//remove the space
            sSwitchTypeContainer = sTemp.toString();//1-->converting StringBuffer to String
            dCost = Double.valueOf(sSwitchTypeContainer);//2-->converting String to Double
            obj_publication.setCost(dCost);//3-->recording variable in object
            iCountSpace++;//4-->increase space number
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());//-->reset value of sTemp String Buffer
          }
         break;
         case 5://case 5 space is int publication_nbpages
          sTemp.append(cTemp);//concatenation
          if(j == (sContainer.length()-1)){//if it's the last char of the line
            sSwitchTypeContainer = sTemp.toString();
            iPublication = Integer.valueOf(sSwitchTypeContainer);
            obj_publication.setPages(iPublication);
            iCountSpace++;
            sTemp.delete(0, sTemp.length());
           }
         break;
         default:
         break;
         }//end of switch case
       }//end of for loop J
  PublicationArray[i] = obj_publication;
  }//end of else
 }//end of foor loop i
```

Comment: What does your output method look like?

Comment: If you've found the answer to your question then you should be posting it as an answer, not as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED!

*updating my post because of @Servy comment*
I was using **one** object as a container. Then I was updating it's value and placing it in the array.
I thought I was creating multiple objects but since it was the same *reference*, it was updating ALL the objects placed in the array.

In other words, instead of creating multiple objects with their own reference I created multiple references to one object.
I added a loop to create empty objects in the array:

```
Publication[] PublicationArray = new Publication[iSize];
for(int i=0; i<iNumberOfItems; i++){
    PublicationArray[i] = new Publication();
}
```

Instead of setting the object like this: `obj_publication.setName(String)` I needed to do something like that `PublicationArray[i].setName(String)`

Voilà! My headache is gone.